# gwt click event document

Tags: gwt, events, click, document

i need to register a cross platform and version independent click event to the document.
that means i have a two text box and submit button but when i click outside of the two text box and submit button then
alert will be displayed .how can i achive this by gwt

document.get().addMouseClick ???

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that comes to mind is to wrap everything in a [`FocusPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html):

```
ClickHandler clickHandler = new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Window.alert("TextBox/Button clickHandler.");
            event.stopPropagation(); // The important line - We stop the event
                                     // propagation here so that the FocusPanel
                                     //  doesn't get the event
        }
    };
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
Button button = new Button("Test");
button.addClickHandler(clickHandler);


// Since FocusPanel is a SimplePanel, it can only have one child, so we are
// wrapping everything additionally in a HorizontalPanel
HorizontalPanel hPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
hPanel.add(textBox);
hPanel.add(button);


FocusPanel focusPanel = new FocusPanel(hPanel);
focusPanel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Window.alert("Outside."); // Clicked outside of the TextBox/Button
    }
});

RootPanel.get().add(focusPanel);
```

The downside is that you need to assign `ClickHandler`s to every element you don't want an alert for (you can use the same `ClickHandler` for that to save memory - like I did above). Other than that, the [`FocusPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html) implementation should ensure that the onclick behavior stays cross-browser.