# GWT: How can I only trigger the button click event when the button is in a panel?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a button in a horizontal panel. Both the button and panel have click handler.

When I click the button, I only want the button click handler to work but not the panel one, but it triggers both.

How can I avoid triggering the panel click handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `event.stopPropagation()` in your click handler. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662877/gwt-click-event-document) for an example.

Comment: Great! I was thinking of testing event location.. but this is apparently so much easier.